# ffmpeg: overlaying two videos is deliting audio from one

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm trying to overlay two videos with ffmpeg, but in the output there is only the audio of the first video.
Using

```
ffmpeg -i screen.mkv -vf "movie=webcam.mp4, scale=600: -1 [inner]; [in][inner] overlay = main_w - (overlay_w + 10) : main_h - (overlay_h + 10)" output.mp4
```

from cmd, in the final output i have only the audio from the first video specfied (screen.mkv).
how can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 inputs, a complex filtergraph, and `-map` output options:

```
-i webcam.mp4
-i screen.mkv
-filter_complex [0:v]scale=600:-1[inner]; 
                [1:v][inner]overlay=main_w-(overlay_w+10):main_h-(overlay_h+10)[vout]
-map [vout] -map 0:a output.mp4
```

Comment: No such filter: ''
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: writing it in one line: ffmpeg -i screen.mkv -i webcam.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]scale=600:-1[inner];[1:v][inner] overlay=main_w-(overlay_w+10):main_h-(overlay_h+10)[vout] -map [vout] -map 0:a output.mp4